# Построить график на основе имени столбца и его значении Python

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, визуализация

Имеется таблица данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

необходимо построить график в котором будут отображены значение столбцов в зависимости от года (имя столбца). Заранее спасибо за помощь. Вот код:

```
import pandas as pd
stat2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/miste/Desktop/data/Population-EstimatesData.csv", low_memory=False, sep= ',')
new = stat2[stat2['Indicator Code'] == 'SH.DTH.IMRT.MA']
austr = new[new['Country Name']=='Australia']
```

По итогу хочу получить график вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не знаю как сопоставить значения из таблице с заголовком столбца.

[Исходники](https://www.kaggle.com/tunguz/population-estimates-and-projections?select=Population-EstimatesData.csv)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Вас попросили предоставить воспроизводимый пример `исходных данных`.

Comment: Добавила ссылку на исходный CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
# выбираем нужную строку данных
austr = stat2.loc[stat2['Indicator Code'].eq('SH.DTH.IMRT.MA') & stat2['Country Name'].eq('Australia')]

# преобразовываем данные из широкого формата в высокий (транспонирование)
d = austr.filter(regex=r"(?:19|20)\d\d").T.iloc[:, 0]

# конвертируем года из строк в числа 
d.index = pd.to_numeric(d.index)

# рисуем график
d.plot()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо, а суммировать значения из одного столбца(допустим данные из пяти стран) и вывести обобщённый результат на график возможно?

Comment: @MarishkaYchitsa, советую открыть новый вопрос и привести в нем эскиз того, что вы хотите получить в результате